# jqGrid: Multiple invocations of 'add' fails

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Upon initial load, the built-in "add" function works as expected so long as the modal dialog isn't canceled. However, after canceling the dialog subsequent invocations of "add" results in an empty field being POSTed for the search parameter (in this case 'name').

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var s = {};
    jQuery("#taggrid").jqGrid({
        jsonReader : {root:"gridModel"},
        url:"jsonGridTag.action",
        datatype:"json",
        mtype:"POST",
        colNames:['tag_id','name','usage count'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id',sortable:true,search:false},
            {name:'name',index:'name',width:400,editable:true,edittype:"text",sortable:true,search:true,searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','bw','ew']}},
            {name:'count',index:'count',formatter:"formatLink",sortable:true,search:true,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}}
        ],
        rowNum:300,
        rowList:[300,1000,5000,10000],
        sortname:'name',
        sortorder:'asc',
        sortableRows:true,
        caption:'Tags',
        gridview:true,
        pager:'#pager',
       toppager:true,
        loadonce:false,
        editurl:'jsonGridTagEdit.action',
        cellurl:'jsonGridTagEdit.action',
        cellEdit:false,
        multiselect:true,
        viewrecords:true
    });
    jQuery("#taggrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{
        edit:true,
        add:true,
        del:true,
        refresh:true,
        view:true,
        search:true,
        cloneToTop:true,
    });
};
```

The problem is clear, just not the solution...

Comment: where is the code that you call add function? I couldn't understand what you mean by "works as expected so long as the dialog modal isn't canceled"

Comment: I'm using the default "add" functionality of jqGrid ("add:true").  Add works fine, the first time it's invoked.  Once you cancel the dialog, and try to invoke add again, it fails (specifically, jqGrid POSTs an empty string).

Comment: What is "works fine" for you? It sends the data you want? And what is "it fails"? It sends empty data when you click submit button? Those options: `edit: true, add: true`, etc. are just to enable or disable the buttons on the footer of the grid, nothing else

Comment: "Works fine" means that (1) I can bring up the add dialog, (2) I can add new rows to the database successfully, (3) I can repeat adding rows to the database.  If I then cancel the add dialog, and bring up a new add dialog, (2) and (3) fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problem sending extra data, you must implement it on the onclickSubmit event like this:

```
$("#taggrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:false,refresh:true},        
    {}, //edit options        
    //add options   
    { 
        url:"../Controller?action=editUser", // CHANGE TO YOUR URL
        closeAfterEdit:true,
        reloadAfterSubmit:true,
        onclickSubmit: function(params, postdata) {
            // here, jqGrid will automatically send these fields to your Servlet (if you're using java): id, name and count. They came from colModel.   
            // if you want to send extra data to your Servlet, you must send it on return like this:
            return {
                another_field: VALUE,
                one_more_field: VALUE
            }
        }
    },      
    {}, //del options
    {}, //search options
    {} //refresh options
```

You can see more info about jqGrid events on [this link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing)

Comment: I will try that, but I don't think that's the issue.  I'm not interesting in sending additional data.  I am simply trying to get the add function on successive invocations.  The first invocation works as expected; subsequent invocations fail.  I'm sure this isn't expected stock behavior.

Comment: Now I understood your problem. Can you provide the code that you use to submit data to your server-side?